# How to create the model in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have declared the model, resources in file config.xml, then i try to create necessary files for module. there are 3 files:

- `app/code/local/MW/SimpleNews/Model/News.php`
- `app/code/local/MW/SimpleNews/Model/Mysql4/News.php`
- `app/code/local/MW/SimpleNews/Model/Mysql4/News/Collection.php`

But I don't know how to make these files correspondent with the table.

Please help

Comment: Mysql4 is deprecated so use resource instead of it. Use [this](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf) official magento extension development guideline as a reference to develop the magento extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Your files seems correct. However you need to configure set up resource in order to integrate custom table with your module. Set up resource is used to declare, update tables associated with a module.

For this, you need to set up resource for your module in `config.xml` and then in the root directory of your module, you need to create `sql\<module>_setup\install.<version_number>.php` file.

You can use this [official tutorial as a reference](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)